# How to map an object's keys to make JSON easier to handle in React

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

If I have this JSON:

```
{
    'name': 'Active user',
    'config': {
        'status': 'active',
    }
},
{
    'name': 'Paused user',
    'config': {
        'status': 'active',
    }
}
```

Then I can render a React component and access the data easily:

```
render: function() {
    var panels = [];

    this.props.accounts.forEach(function(account) {
        panels.push(
            <Tabs.Panel title={account.name}>
                <h2>{account.name}</h2>
            </Tabs.Panel>
        );
    });

    return (<Tabs>{panels}</Tabs>);
}
...
React.render(<Tabs accounts={ACCOUNTS} />, document.body);
```

If my JSON is structured as below instead, how should I re-factor the `render` function to work as I want?

```
{
    'Active User': {
        'config': {
            'status': 'active',
        }
    },
    'Paused User': {
        'config': {
            'status': 'paused',
        }
    }
}
```

i.e. I no longer have a `name` attribute to display.

Comment: To those down voting, is it the vagueness of my question? I wasn't sure of the right way to describe the difference in the file structure. Any info would be much appreciated to improve the quality.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Did you Search and research before asking?

Comment: I did: I found similar questions but nothing that actually explained what the problem was. You're right though, in hindsight I should have been able to use them to resolve my own issue. Still, mark it as a duplicate if you believe it's been covered elsewhere.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
var users = {
    'Active User': {
        'config': {
            'status': 'active',
        }
    },
    'Paused User': {
        'config': {
            'status': 'paused',
        }
    }
};

var usersWithName = Object.keys(users).map(function(key) {
  var user = users[key];
  user.name = key;
  return user;
});
```

Where `usersWithName` = `[{"config":{"status":"active"},"name":"Active User"},{"config":{"status":"paused"},"name":"Paused User"}]`

Comment: This was great thanks. It was also the difference between an array and an array-like object that was tripping me up. Your map function made me realise what I was doing wrong overall.